# IE Metro app (html5/javascript) check if already installed

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-metro

How does Internet Explorer use the meta tags(msApplication-ID, msApplication-PackageFamilyName) to check if a metro app written in (html5/javascript) is already installed?